# Concat a list column in R

Tags: r, dplyr, tidyverse, tibble

I'm trying to concatenate characters within a list column in R.
When I try this approach, the result is not 'abc' but a vector converted to character.
What is the right approach?

```r
library(tidyverse)
tibble(b=list(letters[1:3])) %>% 
  mutate(b = paste(b))
#> # A tibble: 1 x 1
#>   b                       
#>   <chr>                   
#> 1 "c(\"a\", \"b\", \"c\")"
```

<sup>Created on 2020-10-14 by the [reprex package](https://reprex.tidyverse.org) (v0.3.0)</sup>

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this. Keep in mind that the element in your tibble is a list. So you can use any of these approaches:

```
library(tidyverse)
tibble(b=list(letters[1:3])) %>% 
  mutate(b = lapply(b,function(x)paste0(x,collapse = '')))
```

Or this:

```
#Code 2
tibble(b=list(letters[1:3])) %>% 
  mutate(b = sapply(b,function(x)paste0(x,collapse = '')))
```

Output:

```
# A tibble: 1 x 1
  b    
  <chr>
1 abc
```

In the first case, you will get the result in a list whereas in the second one you will get it as a value.

Comment: You are so fast! Great answer, +1!

Answer (score 2):

Maybe you need something like below

```
library(tidyverse)
tibble(b=list(letters[1:3])) %>% 
  mutate(b = sapply(b,paste,collapse = ""))
```

giving

```
# A tibble: 1 x 1
  b
  <chr>
1 abc
```

Answer (score 0):

We can use `tidyverse`

```
library(dplyr)
library(stringr)
library(purrr)
tibble(b=list(letters[1:3])) %>%
     mutate(b = map_chr(b, str_c, collapse=""))
# A tibble: 1 x 1
#  b    
#  <chr>
#1 abc
```